# facebook like box make profile picture smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-like

I have a Facebook like box on my site but in some resolutions the profile pictures goes to next line after 2 pictures instead of 3 so I want to make the profile pictures width and height 49 instead of 50 because that would fix the problem.

Here's how it looks in with lower resolutions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GW7N.png

And here's how its supposed to look https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aD4k.png

So how can I reduce the pictures width and height by 1px with either JavaScript or CSS?

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="facebookpage" data-width="180" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file

```
fb-like-box img {
    height: 49px !important;
    width: 49px !important;
}
```